# How to define type for form submit? (expecting ObjectContaining instead getting SyntheticEvent)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, casting, jestjs, react-testing-library

Using typescript, react, jest and [react-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/).

The following code is used:

**Form.tsx**

```js
export interface IFormProps {
  handleSubmit: (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => void;
}

const Form: React.FC<IFormProps> = (props: IFormProps) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
      <FormControl>
        <Input name="myInput" data-testid="myInputId" />
      </FormControl>
      <Button type="submit" data-testid="mySubmitButton">Submit form</Button>
    </form>
  )
};
```

**Page.tsx**

```js
class Page extends React.Component {
  //...
  public handleSubmit = <T extends React.FormEvent>(event: T) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // do stuff with it
  }
  //...
}
```

**form.test.tsx**

```js
it('submits the form data ', () => {
  const handleSubmit = jest.fn();

  const { getByTestId } = render(<Form handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />);

  const input = getByTestId('myInputId') as HTMLInputElement;
  const submitButton = getByTestId('mySubmitButton') as HTMLButtonElement;

  fireEvent.change(input, {
      target: { value: 'some test value' }
    });

  // API: fireEvent(node: HTMLElement, event: Event)
  fireEvent.click(submitButton);

  expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

  /* 
   * the following outputs the failed test output below 
   */
  expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    expect.objectContaining({
      "value": "some test value",
    })
  );
}
```

**Output:**

```
    - Expected
    + Received

    - ObjectContaining {
    -   "value": "some test value",
    + SyntheticEvent {
    +   "_dispatchInstances": null,
    +   "_dispatchListeners": null,
    +   "_targetInst": null,
    +   "bubbles": null,
    // ...etc.
```

Tried the steps in this medium blogpost: https://medium.com/@evanteague/creating-fake-test-events-with-typescript-jest-778018379d1e

However they are too specific for that use-case. Trying to reproduce it following the steps also hasn't been working so far.

How can the type be defined for this test function?

Comment: How is `handleSubmit` called in `Form.tsx`? Can you update the `Form.tsx` react element tree. Currently there, there is no reference to `handleSubmit` prop?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Sure! Added the reference in the form component as well where it's used on another page. (Since it's used via the props)

Comment: Also added the API for the fireevent as described here: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events#fireevent Since the Medium blog post adjusts the event type.

Comment: This doesn't look right. In your `Form` component you never call the `handleSubmit` function

Comment: Added it to the form @Gpx

Comment: Ok, so what I don't have clear: is your test not working or is typescript not working?

Comment: They're both working. However, the test is failing because of the difference between the _expected_ and _received_ value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faced exactly same case, managed to deal with it checking the expected `value` directly in `mock.calls`, like that:

```
fireEvent.click(submitButton);
expect(handleSubmit.mock.calls[0][0].target.value).toEqual("some test value");
```